# How do I make my website’s layout work gracefully with different browser window sizes, like Tumblr does?

Tags: html, css

i start to study asp.Net now,
i understand basic html (css not)
i need your help how to create my website fit with web browser,

like this :
[image]

when i resize first

[image]

and last
[image]

i try create with my own skill and my website in a mess

Comment: Please provide code on what you've already attempted. As is the answer to this question would require explaining the concepts of fluid layout, which is a bit time consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called an [adaptive layout technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/switchymclayout/) but more recently coined [responsive web design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) (both great articles). A gallery of websites that employ this technique can be found at [mediaqueri.es](http://mediaqueri.es/).

The guts of it is based around using CSS to style your website for the default "wide view" then using `@media` CSS queries to apply extra CSS rules for specific screen dimensions. For example:

```
body { color:red; }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body { color:green; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    body { color:blue; }
}
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/6LX9n](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/6LX9n/show/)** *(resize width of window to see in action)*